# LaTeX Error: Command \citename already defined. Package biblatex Error: Incompatible package 'mciteplus'

Tags: biblatex, achemso

I have used the following packages in Overleaf.

```
\documentclass[journal=jacsat,manuscript=article]{achemso}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem} % Formula subscripts using \ce{}

\newcommand*\mycommand[1]{\texttt{\emph{#1}}}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.5cm}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{textcomp,gensymb}
\usepackage{apalike}
\let\bibhang\relax
\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref,graphicx,float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,makecell}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow}
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\ora}{\overrightarrow}

\setlength{\parskip}{0.3em}

\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Your document class `achemso` already loads packages for citations and the bibliography. Those packages are BibTeX-based and thus incompatible with `biblatex`. You should not and cannot use `biblatex` with that class.

Get rid of the

```
\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}
```

and

```
\addbibresource{references.bib}
```

in your document.

Use the BibTeX-based

```
\bibliography{references}
```

in the place in your document where you want to print the bibliography instead.